# can I use Numpy genfromtxt to get names then skip a specifc row before continuing?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a series of large CSV files contain sensor data samples.

The format of each file is

```
Row 0 Column names

Row 1 Column unit of measurement.

Row 2 to EOF: time-stamp of sample was taken,voltage measurement from all sensors.....
```

I cannot modify the original file

So i would like to use `numpy.gentromtxt(filename,Names=True,delimiter=',',dtype=None)`

So far to avoid corrupting the output i have skipped the header lines and manually added the column names later. 
This is not ideal as each file potentially a different order of sensors- and the information is there for the taking.

Any help/Direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can see several options:

- Open the file to read just the header line, parse the names yourself; run `genfromtxt` with the custom names and skip_header
- trick `genfromtxt` into treating the 2nd line as a comment line
- open the file yourself; pass lines through a filter to `genfromtxt`.  The filter function would remove the second line.  (`genfromtxt` works with a list of lines, or anything that feeds it lines).
  -

Comment: 1. I was hoping to avoid that but I may take this approach. 2. how would one trick genfromtxt without modifying the original file?